# How to comprehend expression/pattern in find/grep/rsync?

Tags: regex, grep, find, glob, rsync

I have to use *find*, *grep* and *rsync* commands for my program. Generally, I rarely used all of these in a single script so didn't notice earlier. Is there a category of *regular-expression* that fit these commands like:

```
find command: follows regex type1
grep command: follows regex type2
rsync command: follows regex type3
```

For example, for finding all the paths which lead to my program log file, we can do:

```
find -type f -name "foo.log*"
```

Here, in the above command, the *star* is not acting like a proper regular expression, as in regex, the *star* corresponds to the zero/one/multiple instances of the immediate before expression which is *character('g')* in this case? So if it actually follows regex, it can match filenames like:

```
foo.lo
foo.log
foo.logg
foo.loggg
and so on...
```

Similar to *find* command, the *rsync* behave when given expression for its source and destination path. While on the other hand, I noticed the *grep* command do follow the regular expression.

So, in total:

1. Do all of these commands follow a different kind of regular expression?
2. Or some of them follows regex while some of them do not, and if not, then what pattern they follow? Basically, I'm looking for the generalisation of the patterns of all these tools?

I'm new to Linux tools. Please guide!

Comment: GNU find (see: `find -regextype help`), GNU grep (depends on the option used: regex, extended regex, Perl-compatible regex, see: `man grep`) and rsync (glob)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big difference between wildcards and regular expressions.

**Wildcards:**

- special characters that define a simple search pattern
- used by shells (bash, old MS-DOS, ...), and by many unix commands (find, ...)
- limited set of wildcards, typically just:

  - `*` - zero or more chars (any combination)
  - `?` - exactly one char (any char)
  - `[`...`]` - exactly one char out of a set or range of chars, such as `[0-9a-f]` for a hex digit
- see tutorial: https://linuxhint.com/bash_wildcard_tutorial/

**Regular Expression:**

- a sequence of characters that define a search pattern

  - think of regular expressions (regex for short) as wildcards on steroids
- regex patterns are used to **find** or **find and replace** strings
- powerful language, natively supported by most programming languages
- there are different flavors of regular expressions, typically grouped into these categories:

  - POSIX Basic (BRE - Basic Regular Expressions)
  - POSIX Extended (ERE - Extended Regular Expressions)
  - Perl and PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions)
  - JavaScript
  - many more flavors, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular-expression_engines
- some unix commands allow you to select one regex flavor or another; for example:

  - `grep` uses POSIX Basic by default
  - `grep -E` or `egrep` uses POSIX Extended
  - `grep -P`uses Perl
- Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression
- tutorial: https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex