# How to use grep to match the files?

Tags: grep

I am trying to learn RegEx, but it is hard.

For example, i have 3 files:

```
$ ls
thisisnothing12.txt  Thisisnothing12.txt  thisisnothing.txt
```

I want to use ls to grep out only the 2 files with digits on it..
These are what i have tried, but they doesn't show even a single file.. why ? What's wrong with em ?

```
$ ls | grep "^[\w]+[\d]+\.[\w]{3}$"
$ ls | grep "^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{3}$"
```

Thx.

Comment: Can you try with `ls -1` instead?

Comment: Just use `printf '%s\n' *[0-9]*`

Comment: I am relatively new with linux, i have to learn one by one, ask me to use printf, without  knowing how those characters works.. i won't improve at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different regex flavors, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66256100/7475450

You need to use PCRE if you want to use `\d`:

```
$ touch thisisnothing12.txt  Thisisnothing12.txt  thisisnothing.txt
$ ls
Thisisnothing12.txt  thisisnothing.txt  thisisnothing12.txt
$ ls | grep '\d'    # '\d' does not work in POSIX Basic regex
$ ls | grep -P '\d' # use PCRE regex
Thisisnothing12.txt
thisisnothing12.txt
$
```

As you can see you can search for just the characters you are interested in.

You can narrow down, such as finding files that start with a number:

```
$ touch 2feet.txt
$ ls | grep -P '\d'
2feet.txt
Thisisnothing12.txt
thisisnothing12.txt
$ ls | grep -P '^\d'
2feet.txt
$
```

Learn more with this tutorial: https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex

Answer (score 1):

```
^[\w]+[\d]+\.[\w]{3}$
^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{3}$
```

Let's simplify a bit. They are both essentially the same thing, because `[\w]` is the same as `\w` which is `[A-Za-z]`. And the same for `\d`.

So we can simplify to

```
^\w+\d+\.\w{3}$
```

The issue is that `^` asserts the start of the string, and `$` is the end. `grep` works on each line. And `ls` returns all results on one line. You can use `ls -1` to get one file per line. You also need the `-P` flag for grep to work with `\w` and `\d`.

```
$ ls -1 | grep -P "^\w+\d+\.\w{3}$"
```

You can try different regexes here: https://regexr.com/5mujo